# Is there a secure way to create and distribute Shamir Secrets?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

This [Shamir Secret sharing utility](http://sourceforge.net/projects/secretsharp/) consumes the secret key, and then generates N keys that must be manually distributed to each person.

This is probably fine for most low-security situations, but not suitable in medium or high security scenarios where no-one can know all the keys, or the secret key that was created in the beginning.

- Given this new requirement, what pre-existing systems provision the Shamir secrets in a secure manner?  How do they work?
- Is there add-in cryptography that makes the secure creation and distribution of Shamir Secrets more trustworthy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as a one-dimensional scale of security which would allow to rate all or even most scenarios as low, medium or high security. Every scenario has context, requirements, goals, and overall an *attack model*.

In any case, [Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) is "perfect", in that it is one of the very few algorithms which offer unconditional security: even infinitely powerful computers could not break the features offered by that scheme.

What are these features ? Namely:

- The algorithm works in a finite field ***K***. Practical implementations use *GF(256)*, i.e. *bytes*.
- Let *m* be a sequence of elements of ***K*** (i.e., some bytes).
- Let *n* be the "number of shares" and *t* the "threshold" such that *n* ≥ *t* ≥ 1.
- The algorithm produces *n* "shares", where each share is a sequence of elements of ***K*** of the same length as *m*. The shares are such that any subset of *t* shares is sufficient to efficiently rebuild *m*; but any subset of *t-1* shares yields no information whatsoever on *m* (except, of course, its length).

Regardless of its perfection, the algorithm is only for *transit*: at the time the shares are produced, the value *m* exists as a whole in some physical system; and when the value *m* must be rebuilt, it is *rebuilt*: it again exists as a whole in some other physical system. The splitting operates only between these two points in space-time. It is sufficient for some usages, some of which being possibly "high security"; I have used it, for instance, to split a backup copy of a master key in a smart card management system (the master key does exist in a specific system; the backup was done to be able to recover from a catastrophic loss such as a flood or fire).

**No algorithm does everything.** There are scenarios where the security features of Shamir's Secret Sharing do not match that which is needed. In a context of "shares" and "threshold", there are, for instance, [group signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_signature): this is meant for situations where digital signatures must be produced, with no single entity being able to generate signatures on its own. But we also want this property to be maintained even if many signatures are produced. If you wanted to use Shamir's Secret Sharing for that, then you would split a normal signature private key, and rebuild it when signing, but this requires a "trusted system", both for key generation and key usage. That system would, transiently, acquire knowledge of the full key. If this is unacceptable to you, then you have to do something else, and that's what group signature algorithms are meant for. A group signature allows for a signature to be generated by the collective actions of sufficiently many key share owners, without the private key being disclosed to any of them, however dishonest he may be.

Group algorithms are inherently more restrictive than Shamir's Secret Sharing since they do not, by definition, rebuild the secret that was split; as such, they can only compute a specific function involving the secret (e.g. signature generation or asymmetric decryption). On the other hand, good group algorithms can avoid to some extent the need for a trusted system (many group signatures have honesty thresholds: if sufficiently many malicious key share owners cooperate with each other, they may gain some extra power).

Group algorithms are no more or no less secure than Shamir's Secret Sharing; they just do something else.

Comment: If a group is used for asymmetric encryption, then that encrypting node needs to be trusted, right?  Is there a way to eliminate that trust?

Comment: I am not sure your question makes sense. Asymmetric encryption is about protecting the confidentiality of some data -- data which already exists. With group _decryption_, the collaborating private key owners recover the original plaintext, and they all get it; the point is that they do not reveal each other their _key shares_: further decryption will still need a threshold of key owners.

Comment: I'll try to ask differently.  If I have a secret X, when using the Shamir method, a person or trusted system must know X in order to split that secret.  The Group method would encrypt X, but would also need a person or system that is trusted.  My question is about dynamically composing a secret that no-one knows, and decrypting it.  I don't think I'm crazy because [these ECC keys have an additive property](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/29/1821) that provides secrecy. (regarding me being crazy - I'm definitely naive in crypto and respect the fact I have much to learn, might be way offtrack)

Comment: Oh and I assume that `"collaborating private key owners recover the original plaintext"` is where `"plaintext"` can equal a secret key

Comment: "Dynamically composing a secret that no-one knows, and decrypting it": that is called Diffie-Hellman, when you think about it. The "shares" are the private/public DH pairs for both participants, that they generate freely, and they build the shared secret by combining their private key with the public key from the peer.

Comment: That is very cool, I'll be thinking about that for a bit.

Comment: A year later, I think I rephrased my question better: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/65257/396